Managing Inconsistent Model Attribute State on WebSocket Reconnect (Django Channels)
I'm working on an online battleship game with React Django_channels and i'm having problems maintaining data consistency of a "lobby phase" attribute in my Django model, this attribute should work to transition the lobby from a "waiting for another player to join" UI to a "setup" phase so that users can modify their ships position and finally there would be a "game" phase to let the actual match begin.
Due to what i've seen from my consumers.py logs i'm pretty sure that the error lies somewhere in here in the async def connect(self): method.
import json, jwt, uuid, random
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from django.conf import settings
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from .models import GameRoom

class BattleshipConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_id']
        token = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['token']

        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=['HS256'])
            self.username = payload['username']
            self.guest_id = payload['guest_id']

            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                self.room_group_name,
                self.channel_name
            )
            await self.accept()

            # Fetch the current state of the room
            self.room = await sync_to_async(GameRoom.objects.get)(room_name=self.room_group_name)
            initial_lobby_phase = self.room.lobby_phase

            # Log current state before making changes
            print(f"Initial room state for {self.username}: {initial_lobby_phase}")

            # Check if player1 or player2 is None and assign self.guest_id accordingly
            if self.room.player1 is None and self.room.player2 != self.guest_id:
                self.room.player1 = self.guest_id
                print(f'{self.username} has been added as player1')
                await sync_to_async(self.room.save)()
            elif self.room.player2 is None and self.room.player1 != self.guest_id:
                self.room.player2 = self.guest_id
                self.room.lobby_phase = 'setup'

                # Save the updated room and fetch it again to ensure consistency
                await sync_to_async(self.room.save)()
                print(f'{self.username} has been added as player2')
                self.room = await sync_to_async(GameRoom.objects.get)(room_name=self.room_group_name)
                #this works correctly, the lobby phase sent here is 'setup',as expected 
                print("broadcasting phase change to setup")
                await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                    self.room_group_name,
                    {
                        'type': 'phase_change',
                        'phase': self.room.lobby_phase
                    }
                )

            # Fetch the latest state from the database after making changes
            self.room = await sync_to_async(GameRoom.objects.get)(room_name=self.room_group_name)
            lobby_phase = self.room.lobby_phase

            # Log updated state after changes
            print(f"Current room state for {self.username}: {lobby_phase}")

            chat_history = await sync_to_async(self.room.get_chat_history)()
            shots_fired_history = await sync_to_async(self.room.get_shots_fired_history)(self.guest_id)
            shots_received_history = await sync_to_async(self.room.get_shots_received_history)(self.guest_id)

            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'type': 'restore_game_history',
                'lobby_phase': lobby_phase,
                'chat_history': chat_history,
                'shots_fired': shots_fired_history,
                'shots_received': shots_received_history
            }))

            msg = f'{self.username} has joined the room'
            message_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
            await sync_to_async(self.room.add_chat_message)('Server', msg, message_id)
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.room_group_name,
                {
                    'type': 'chat_message',
                    'message': msg,
                    'username': 'Server',
                    'message_id': message_id
                }
            )

        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            await self.close(code=4001)
        except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
            await self.close(code=4002)

Now, since im changing 'lobby_phase' on player2 being added and am taking the value to broadcast directly from my model instance right after, id expect player1 on refresh to have an updated lobby_phase value, which doesnt happen, remaining the default value 'waiting'. p2 refreshing instead gets the correct value and this inconsistency is driving me crazy.
logs for reference

p1 aka Keke connects, print 'lobby_phase' gets added as player1, print 'lobby_phase'  again.
p2 aka Baba connects,  print 'lobby_phase' , gets added as p2, changes lobby_phase value broadcasts phase_change taking value directly from db,  print 'lobby_phase' (and its correct).
client 2 refreshes and on both print has correct lobby phase value, while client1 refreshes and has 'waiting' once again.
I would guess the problem has to do with the asynchronous functions called on my db, but it still wouldnt make any sense for the clients to have different values so im honestly clueless.
At least i'm sure the problem has to be in the backend and that the frontend changes UI based on phase recived...

Can you add the code for GameRoom model? Is this the only place where lobby_phase can be set?
